# Is it possible to read SMS from device in Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

Is it possible to read messages(SMS) from device inbox from app using Smartface. Need to implement this for OTP message fetching automatically.

Can any one help in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do see this link if it helps you :

https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/device/telephony/